# How to show alert after unwind transition in iOS?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I'm implementing Login in iOS. I want to unwind to the previous VC(IntroVC) first, and to show completed sign up alert about completed in IntroVC.

(completingSignUp is Unwind function.)

```
@IBAction func completingSignUp(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let completedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Completing", message: "Congratulations.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        completedAlert.addAction(ok)
        self.present(completedAlert, animated: true)
    }
```

It shows only the alert without unwind to IntroVC.

I think the location of the alert code seems to be incorrect.

Where should I write alert code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code into IntroVC‘s `viewDidAppear`. You will need to introduce a condition so that the alert is presented only when you are coming back via the unwind segue.

Comment: Personally I would use protocol-and-delegate pattern so the LoginVc could tell the IntroVc what just happened.